# How can I make this code shorter (less lines etc)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code and want to make it as short as possible, is there any way i can?

```
text = raw_input("Give me some text > ")
list1 = []
for char in text:
  num = ord(char)
  if num in range(48,57):
    print "ERROR 319: Number entered"
    quit()
  elif num in range(65,90) or num in range (97,122):
    upper = char.upper()
    list1.append(upper)
num1 = 0
vowelCount = 0 
conCount = 0
for x in range(len(list1)):
  if list1[num1] == "A" or list1[num1] == "E" or list1[num1] == "I" or list1[num1] == "O" or list1[num1] == "U":
    vowelCount = vowelCount + 1
  else:
    conCount = conCount + 1
  num1 = num1 + 1 
print "Vowels: " +str(vowelCount) + " Consonants: " + str(conCount)
```

Comment: These questions are more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Here, we help you understand why something works (or doesn't), not beautify code for you.

Comment: Maybe even better for Code Golf than for Code Review.

Comment: Careful with Code Golf... you'll get something inhuman and unreadable, but very short!

Comment: @RPGillespie: Agreed, but the OP did say, "as short as possible". One must be careful what one asks for.

Comment: If you just search for "python detect vowels" or "python get vowels" there are more answers than you want to read

Comment: [Best I can get.](https://gist.github.com/RikerW/adfdbba2c2110b96fadccd2668595f34) Py2, i/o is the same as question (`raw_input()` and `print` statements). cc @RPGillespie it's not that unreadable

Answer (score 4):

Instead of taking ord() of the character, you can use the string methods:

```
char.isdigit() # check if a char is a digit
char.isalpha() # check if char is letter
```

For checking the vowel counts, try:

```
vowel_count = len(filter(lambda c: c in "aeiou", list1))
cons_count = len(list1) - vowel_count
```

Comment: A list comprehension may be more readable than `filter`: `vowelCount = len([c for c in text if c.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']])`

Comment: Thank you for your help it has helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Building off of AmourK's answer, you could do something like this:

```
text = raw_input("Give me some text > ")
vowel_count = len(filter(lambda c: c in "aeiou", text))
cons_count  = len(filter(lambda c: c not in "aeiou" and c.isalpha(), text))
print "Vowels: %d Consonants: %d" % (vowel_count, cons_count)
```

Comment: Thanks very much its nice to know I can shorten my code down to four lines from twenty!